# Rails assets not working with webpacker, css, production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, asset-pipeline, webpacker

I got a successful dev env running with webpacker, bootstrap, rails. This is how I am importing bootstrap:

#### 1. added to package.json

```
"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
```

#### 2. Javascript

I have app/javascript/packs/application.js with the following:

```
import "bootstrap"
import "../stylesheets/application"
```

#### Stylesheet

I am importing my stylesheets inside app/javascript/packs/stylesheets:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete";
@import "~easy-autocomplete/dist/easy-autocomplete.themes";
@import "autocomplete";
```

I cant make it to work in production, deploying in ubuntu + nginx set.

I am running rake assets:precomile, and yarn install, doesnt seem to help: My page will render without css, etc.

Comment: Can you explain what "doesnt seem to help" means? Just add any output of any command and/or stack trace.

Comment: If you can provide more details of your setup and pinpoint the issue but for now what I can understand from your problem.

Comment: I updated what 'doesnt seem to help' means: css is not being rendered.

Comment: any updates @MarceloRibeiro

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure the assets are serving from the proper directory, which can be done through below nginx code in the server block,

```
  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
```

Make sure root is pointing to the public folder and it contains assets folder after compiling assets.

Comment: Any change you have any other ideas of what could cause this, I have the same issue, but already have a line similar to what you posted in nginx:

`location ~ ^/(assets|packs)`

Comment: Try this one if you are using rails 6,
       location ~ ^/(packs|assets|uploads)/ {
            root { public location path };
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header ETag "";
            break;
        }

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, in my specific case the aplication.css file was not getting fingerprinted, I needed to set asset digest for the production environment to resolve.  If you happen to have the same issue my solution is included below.

**app/config/environments/production.rb**

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

Unfortunately, I cannot explain why this was necessary as the default is true per the [Rails Docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

> Fingerprinting is enabled by default for both the development and
>   production environments. You can enable or disable it in your
>   configuration through the config.assets.digest option.

I must be missing something as I should not have had to explicitly set this to true, but doing so resolved my issue.